# How do i scale an object based on a variable from a different script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, scale

I created a force-field for my third-person player-basically a sphere around him.
My player has floats for stamina (curStamina and maxStamina).

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically scale the size of the sphere based on the players current stamina. So the force-field (sphere) is basically meant to be a visual intepretation of the amount of stamina the player currently has (curStamina) and either increases or decreases in size based on curStamina.

Here's my stamina script for reference. Any help on how i would go about this is appreciated!

```
public class Stamina : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float stamina = 100;
    public float maxStamina = 100;
    public float drainPerSecond = 2.0f, gainPerSecond = 1.0f;
    public bool online = false, usingStamina = false;
    //public int lives;
    public GameObject staminaImagePrefab;
    private Transform staminaPanel;
    private Image staminaImage;

    //private Color lerpedColor; // Not currently used
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        if (transform.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            staminaPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("StaminaPanel").transform;
            GameObject staminaObject = Instantiate(staminaImagePrefab, staminaPanel);
            staminaImage = staminaObject.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Image>();
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (usingStamina)
        {
            DrainStamina();
        }
        else
        {
            RegenerateStamina();
        }
        if (transform.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            staminaImage.fillAmount = (float)stamina / maxStamina;
        }
    }

    private void RegenerateStamina()
    {
        stamina += gainPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        if (stamina > maxStamina) stamina = maxStamina;
    }
    public void StaminaDamage(float value)
    {
        stamina -= value;
    }

    private void DrainStamina()
    {
        stamina -= drainPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

        if (stamina < 0)
        {
            // Out of stamina
            stamina = 0;
        }
    }
    public void ResetStamina(float _stamina, float _maxStamina)
    {
        stamina = _stamina;
        maxStamina = _maxStamina;
        if (transform.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            staminaImage.fillAmount = (float)stamina / maxStamina;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture reference]

Comment: Most of the code isn’t relevant: “variable .. different scope”, sure. It doesn’t matter if the value is used to scale or merely display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to implement it :

```
public float MinForceFieldScale = 1f;
public float MaxForceFieldScale = 4f;

[SerializeField]
private Transform forceFieldTransform;

private float DeltaForceFieldScale => MaxForceFieldScale - MinForceFieldScale;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (usingStamina)
    {
        DrainStamina();
    }
    else
    {
        RegenerateStamina();
    }
    if (transform.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        staminaImage.fillAmount = (float)stamina / maxStamina;
    }
    UpdateForceFieldSize();
}

private void UpdateForceFieldSize()
{
    float actualStaminaPercent = stamina / maxStamina;
    float forceFieldSize = MinForceFieldScale + DeltaForceFieldScale * actualStaminaPercent;

    forceFieldTransform.localScale = Vector3.one * forceFieldSize;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I kind of understand the way you approached most of it, i just have one question:

what's the logic behind: private float DeltaForceFieldScale => MaxForceFieldScale - MinForceFieldScale;

Comment: It's just a easy way to create a getter who return the difference between the maximum and the minimum. It's the size range. It's the same as I wrote : `float DeltaForceFieldScale { get { return MaxForceFieldScale - MinForceFieldScale; }}`
You can make a field too if you want `float DeltaForceFieldScale;` and then compute its value on `Start`. More informations about [=> operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) and [get set](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_properties.asp)